# How can i append a an item only if it meets certain rules in python

Tags: python, list, append

i would like to append an item into `list_b` only if it is one above `'5H'`  which is `'6H'`

```
list_a = ('2A','4A','8H','6H')
list_b = ['5H']
```

`list_a.pop()` gives a `'6H'`
therefore if i `append` the `'6H'` it should be able to be added to `list_b` since its just one above `'5H'`.

i tried to compare the first values but it gives an error because the `1` in the code below is an `int` and `list_b[-1][0]` is a `str`.

```
if list_b[-1][0] + 1 != list_a.pop()[0]:
    print('Error')
```

Therefore i cannot use `list_b[-1][0] + 1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presuming that `list_a` really is a list, not a tuple, otherwise `list_a.pop()` won't work ...

You need to do TWO things:

(1) convert the first characters to `int` so that you can compare them properly
(2) check that the second characters are the same ... from your problem description, it would appear that `'6G'` and `'6I'` (amongst many others) are not OK

```
b_value = list_b[-1]
a_value = list_a.pop()

ok = int(b_value[0]) + 1 == int(a_value[0]) and b_value[1] == a_value[1]
```

Answer (score 1):

It should suffice to turn the character into the integer it represents by using `int`:

```
if int(list_b[-1][0]) + 1 != int(list_a.pop()[0]):
    print('Error')
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, your `list_a` is a `tuple`, not a list. Check the parentheses.

If

```
list_a = ['2A','4A','8H','6H']
list_b = ['5H']
```

you can do something like:

```
while list_a:
    t = list_a.pop()
    if int(t[0]) == int(list_b[-1][0]) + 1:
        list_b.append(t)
    else:
        print 'Error'
```

to process the elements of `list_a` iteratively.

Comment: I only need to compare the first value of an item which is referenced by t[0]

Comment: @Lycon:"I only need to compare the first value of an item which is referenced by t[0]" is ambiguous and possibly not consistent with your question. You should update your question, and give examples of what is OK and what is **NOT** OK. Please read my answer before updating your question.

Answer (score 0):

Use a list comprehension:

```
list_b.extend([i for i in list_a if int(i[0]) == (int(list_b[-1][0]) + 1)])
```